# Mock option "Require signed authentication Assertion" on spring-security-saml-1.0.2

Tags: spring-saml

I'm making several configuration tests on spring-security-saml-1.0.2 plugin and I have found that the option "Require signed authentication Assertion" has no effect on the configuration created by the plugin's configuration wizard.

Even if I mark "Yes" or "No" in this option the result is the same:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
   <property name="local" value="true"/>
   <property name="securityProfile" value="pkix"/>
   <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
   <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
   <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
   <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
   <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
   <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
   <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
   <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
   <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Checking this options "Require signed authentication assertion" will not configure the ExtendedMetadata bean.

This option is a "standard" one used to generate the metadata.xml of your SP : `<md:SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true">`

If you try to configure your SP metadata programmatically , you can use the following method : MetagaGenerator.setWantAssertionSigned(boolean).